# Stack overflow and recursive method

Tags: recursion, stack-overflow

Got a little silly question that I hope someone can answer me. When a stack overflow happens, how can a recursive method help in this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Once a stack overflow has happened, nobody can help you, since the program is no longer in a well-defined state.

Answer (score 2):

It's often the case that *unbounded* recursive methods *cause* stack overflow errors. One way to *try to avoid* this is to make the recursion *converge* and to use [tail-call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (if your language supports it).